# CSS files for Django forms

Tags: django, web

I used Bootstrap css file but when I use `{{form.as_p}}` in Django, Bootstrap doesn't support that well. Where can we find css files for Django forms?

Answer (score 1):

Try [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html?highlight=bootstrap#bootstrap-layout-objects), also adds a lot of extra functionality to forms. Or, if you want to keep using Django Forms, try [django-bootstrap-forms](https://github.com/tzangms/django-bootstrap-form) (and use it with `{{ form|bootstrap }}`)

Comment: How do I install and use django-bootstrap-forms?

Comment: See the example app in the repo. Or use django-bootstrap (as Aldarund mentioned) and check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use bootstrap and django there is a perfect library for it [django-bootstrap](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3). Its more maintained than django-bootstrap-forms.